# Convert d3.csv to promise?

Tags: d3.js, promise

Using Angular 5 and I would like to load a CSV file into the async pipe, how do I convert this to a promise?

```
d3.csv(this.csvFile, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Have you seen the [d3.promise](https://github.com/kristw/d3.promise) plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with d3 version 5, promises are built in.

```
d3.csv("file.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you use `async/await` you can do this:

```
const data = await d3.csv("file.csv");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: vote for having async/await example in it as well

Answer (score 0):

With enough googling I worked it out...

```
loadCSV(file: string) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        d3.csv(file, function(error, request) {
            if(error) {
               reject(error);
            } else {
               resolve(request);
            }
         });
     });
 }
```

Comment: Also v5 of d3 is promise based